# Placing commas in number fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a good deal of forms with numerical fields that are used to enter rather large numbers.  I was using some javascript to automatically place a comma to delimit the number to make it easier to read in the form.  **The problem** is that, when the field is saved to the database, the comma in the text field makes it a non-integer, so it only saves the first set of digits (left to right) before it runs into a comma.

**My question is:** What is the best way to handle this?  I figure it must be a relatively common situation, though I can't really find a simple answer.

**I've tried** adding a `before validation` method to strip out the commas, but at that point, the number has been altered.  If I get desperate, I figure I could:

1)  Add a dummy field into my view and hide the integer field

or

2)  Grab and alter the parameters in my controller

or

3)  Override the submit button to run a comma-clensing script prior to submit.

But all of those seem excessive.  Any better practices out there for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or parse it as a string on the server and remove the commas there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY stumbled across the answer.  There's a fantastic jquery plugin called [autonumeric](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric) that formats the appearance of the textbox but not its value attribute.  It even comes in a [well maintained rails gem](https://github.com/randoum/autonumeric-rails) that's STOOPID-easy to use and pretty well documented.  Check it out!

PS, it does not play well with simple form's `f.input`.  You can still use simple form but on any fields you want to format, use `f.text_field` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to leave the number as an integer in the database, but just display it with commas.  please see this link [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

How about allowing the fields to be string fields and then tagging on the `.to_i` method.

**EDIT**

actually you'll need to create a method for handling these input fields and call it `before_save` or something

```
inputname do |i| 
    i.delete!(',').to_i
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that once it gets to the model, the number has been modified so that it's not useful.  Even the `before_validation` happens too late.